# Not sure how to upgrade

Tags: facebook-login

I got this reminder saying I am using "v2.5 " and need to upgrade to higher version. I ran the upgrade wizard and it says this:

> items to fix to upgrade www.dga.org from v2.5 to v2.12:2 Items:
>
> 1- 13 July 2018 v2.7 Facebook Login1.0 "In v2.7 of the API, you will need to request business_management to manage your business account".
>   New
>
> 2- 22 July 2019
>   v2.10
>   Facebook Login1.0
>   "Starts enforcing the app's restrictions (such as country or age ) on API calls made without the application's ' appsecret_proof'in the request".
>   Change

My Java SDKk that I inject from code is as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("<div id=\"fb-root\"></div>");

sb.AppendLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");

sb.AppendLine("window.fbAsyncInit = function () {");
sb.AppendLine("FB.init({");
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("appId: '{0}',", Helper.GetFBAppId()));
sb.AppendLine("status: true,");
sb.AppendLine("cookie: true,");
sb.AppendLine("xfbml: true");
sb.AppendLine("});");
sb.AppendLine("Login();");
sb.AppendLine("};");

sb.AppendLine("(function (doc) {");
sb.AppendLine("var js;");
sb.AppendLine("var id = 'facebook-jssdk';");
sb.AppendLine("var ref = doc.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];");
sb.AppendLine("if (doc.getElementById(id)) {");
sb.AppendLine("return;");
sb.AppendLine("}");
sb.AppendLine("js = doc.createElement('script');");
sb.AppendLine("js.id = id;");
sb.AppendLine("js.async = true;");
sb.AppendLine("js.src = \"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js\";");
sb.AppendLine("ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);");
sb.AppendLine("} (document));");


sb.AppendLine("function Login() {");
sb.AppendLine("FB.login(function (response) {");
sb.AppendLine("if (response.authResponse) {");
sb.AppendLine("FB.ui({");
sb.AppendLine("method: 'share',");
sb.AppendLine("href:");
sb.Append(string.Format("'{0}'", Helper.GetUrl(SC.Context.Item)));
sb.AppendLine("}, function(response){");
sb.AppendLine("if (!response || response.error) {");
sb.AppendLine("alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));");
sb.AppendLine("}");
sb.AppendLine("});");
sb.AppendLine("} else {");
sb.AppendLine(" }");
sb.AppendLine("}, { scope: 'publish_actions' });");
sb.AppendLine("}");

sb.AppendLine("</script>");
```

Please help me understand as to what I need to change as it is not very clear.

Comment: I asked this same question 2 days ago with no response. I went through and added /v2.11/ to all my calls and made sure I didn't pass nil for parameters. Upgrade tool changed slightly but it is still telling me to upgrade GET/{user-id}  <--- it originally said 4.0 right after this but now it says 3.0